# Gulp install globally

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I need install gulp. I used this command: npm install gulp gulp-plumber gulp-sass gulp-autoprefixer gulp-concat gulp-uglify gulp-notify

Unfortunelly in my project It was created node_modules directory. How do I do this? I don't have to add files in any project. I would like to use only command "gulp watch".

Comment: I don't understand what you need . please be clear

Comment: Please clarify what you are ultimately trying to achieve, how, and what is not working.

Answer (score 3):

add `-g` for global installing

```
$ npm install -g gulp
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo npm install -g gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

To install a *npm* package globally on a machine, use one of

- `npm i -g <packages>`
- `npm install --global <packages>`

However, this doesn't let anybody else know about this dependency. Consider instead adding `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore` file (or the ignore of whatever VCS you are using), then install with

- `npm i --save-dev <packages>`

The `--save-dev` here means that it knows that this dependency is only for development and not required in deployment. So if you use a script to deploy which installs the *npm* dependencies, you can have it ignore these packages

Answer (score 0):

Add gulp in your package.json and run npm intall from your project directory.